# Added OOS to SharePoint 2019 - Browsed docs open, searched docs do not

Tags: search, 2019, oos

On Premises SharePoint 2019.  When I browse to a document library and open a file, the document opens into Word Online as intended.  Example:  https://fqdn/sites/site/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BB981B8B9-9561-4887-B569-334C3A45E03D%7D&file=2019_Company_Letterhead_Template.docx&action=default&IsList=1&ListId=%7B0BBE5F0C-F17F-4898-8F73-F25CA1F36283%7D&ListItemId=652.

When I use search and find the document and try to open, I get a 404 error (IE) or it tries to download it (Chrome).  From the link, I can tell it is not looking at OOS.

Example:  https://fqdn/sites/site/Shared%20Documents/KB%20-%20Info/Caseware/2019_Company_Letterhead_Template.docx.

Is there a way to fix this.  Obviously, we cannot turn this feature on if both ways of opening the document are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you performed a Full Crawl since adding the Office Online Server? Usually after adding the server the Search Server needs to know the new addresses for the Open Action.